# Apply !If condition to only one element of list in CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I'm writing CloudFormation template to create CodePipeline. I want to provision Actions in Stages dynamically and for this I'm using `!If` condition. Following is my template

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion:  "2010-09-09"
Description: "CodePipeline"

Parameters:
  ProjectBranch:
    Type: "String"
    Description: "The name of branch"
    Default: "main"

Conditions:
  DisableSonar: !Equals
    - !Ref ProjectBranch
    - main

Resources:

  JavaCodePipeline:

    Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
    Properties:
      ArtifactStore: 
        Location: "s3-artifacts-pipeline-xxxxxxx"
        Type: "S3"
      Name: "TestCodePipeline"
      PipelineType: "V2"
      RoleArn: "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/codepipeline-role"
      Stages: 
        - Actions:
            - ActionTypeId:
                Category: "Source"
                Owner: "AWS"
                Provider: "CodeCommit"
                Version: "1"
              Name: "source"
              RunOrder: 1
              Configuration:
                RepositoryName: "java-application"
                BranchName: "main"
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: !Join [ "-", [ java, application, source ] ]
          Name: "Source"
        - Actions:
            !If
            - DisableSonar
            - 
            - Name: "sonar"
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: "Build"
                Owner: "AWS"
                Provider: "CodeBuild"
                Version: 1
              RunOrder: 1
              Configuration:
                ProjectName: "java-test"
              InputArtifacts:
                - Name: !Join [ "-", [ java, application, source ] ]
            - Name: "test"
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: "Build"
                Owner: "AWS"
                Provider: "CodeBuild"
                Version: 1
              RunOrder: 1
              Configuration:
                ProjectName: "java-sonar"
              InputArtifacts:
                - Name: !Join [ "-", [ java, application, source ] ]
          Name: "Test"

      Tags: 
        - Key: "ManagedBy"
          Value: "CloudFormation"
```

As you can see in the above pipeline, I have two actions under `Resources/JavaCodePipeline/Properties/Stages[1]` named `test` and `sonar`.
I want to disable the `sonar` action whenever the Branch is `main`. I have created a `Condition` named `DisableSonar` but when I try to create the template, I get following error

**[/Resources/JavaCodePipeline/Type/Stages/2/Actions/Fn::If/1] 'null' values are not allowed in templates**

As of my knowledge, the condition is not allowing to create both the Actions (`test` and `sonar`). If anyone can help to implement the condition to only the `sonar` action ?